# Finding the index based on two data frames of strings

Tags: r

One of my data inputs looks like this:

```
O75663  O95456  O75663  O95456 
O95400  O95670  O95400  O95670
O95433          O95433  O95801 
                O95456  P00352
                O95670  

df<- structure(
    list(
        V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", "O95433"), 
                class = "factor"), 
        V2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O95456", "O95670"), 
                class = "factor"), 
        V3 = structure(1:5, 
            .Label = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
                class = "factor"), 
        V4 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352"), 
                class = "factor")), 
    .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), 
        class = "data.frame", 
        row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

My second data input looks like this:

```
O75663 
O95400 
O95433
O95456 
O95670
O95801 
P00352
P00492
```

I want to know for each string from the second data set in which columns of the first data it can be found. It might be in none of them, or several. I want the output to look like the following:

```
strings    column ids 
O75663      1, 3
O95400      1, 3
O95433      1, 3
O95456      2, 3, 4
O95670      2, 3, 4
O95801      4
P00352      4
P00492      NA
```

The new `strs`:

```
strs <- structure(
    list(
        strings = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801"),
                class = "factor"), 
        strings2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95433", "O95456", "P00352", "P00492"), 
                class = "factor"), 
        strings3 = structure(c(4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", "P00492"), 
                class = "factor"), 
        strings4 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
            .Label = c("", "O95400", "O95456", "O95801", "P00492"), 
                class = "factor"), 
        strings5 = structure(c(8L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L), 
            .Label = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", "P00492"), 
                class = "factor")), 
    .Names = c("strings", "strings2", "strings3", "strings4", "strings5"), 
        class = "data.frame", 
        row.names = c(NA, -8L))


lut <- structure(
    list(
        V1 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", NA, NA), 
        V2 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), 
        V3 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
        V4 = c("O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA), 
        V1 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", NA, NA), 
        V2 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), 
        V3 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
        V4 = c("O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA)), 
    .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df<- setDT(strs)[, paste0('colids_',seq_along(strs)) := 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), 
    by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

Then I get this error:

> Error in `df1 == x` : comparison of these types is not implemented
>   In addition: Warning message: In `is.data.frame(x)` :
>   Incompatible methods ("`Ops.data.frame`", "`Ops.factor`") for "`==`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution with base R by using a combination of `colSums`, `which`, `toString` and `apply`:

```
strs$colids <- apply(strs, 1, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0)))
```

which gives:

```
> strs
  strings  colids
1  O75663    1, 3
2  O95400    1, 3
3  O95433    1, 3
4  O95456 2, 3, 4
5  O95670 2, 3, 4
6  O95801       4
7  P00352       4
8  P00492
```

To see what each part does, start by looking at the output of `lut == 'O75663'` which will give you a `TRUE/FALSE` table. By wrapping this in `colSums` you sum the `TRUE/FALSE`. A `0` means that there is no match in that column for that string, a number above zero means that there is one or more matches. With `which` you get the column indexes and by wrapping that in `toString` you get a character values with indexes of the matching columns.

This approach could also be implemented with either `data.table` or `dplyr`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(strs)[, colids := toString(which(colSums(lut == strings, na.rm=TRUE) > 0)), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]

library(dplyr)
strs %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(colids = toString(which(colSums(lut == strings, na.rm=TRUE) > 0)))
```

---

In response to your comment: An example for multiple columns in `strs` with `data.table`:

```
# create an extra strings column
set.seed(1)
strs$strings2 <- sample(strs$strings)

# create two 'colids' columns
library(data.table)
setDT(strs)[, c('colids1','colids2') := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

which gives:

```
   strings strings2 colids1 colids2
1:  O75663   O95433    1, 3    1, 3
2:  O95400   P00492    1, 3        
3:  O95433   O95456    1, 3 2, 3, 4
4:  O95456   O95670 2, 3, 4 2, 3, 4
5:  O95670   O75663 2, 3, 4    1, 3
6:  O95801   P00352       4       4
7:  P00352   O95400       4    1, 3
8:  P00492   O95801               4
```

---

*Used data*:

```
lut <- structure(list(V1 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", NA, NA), 
                      V2 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), 
                      V3 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
                      V4 = c("O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA)), 
                 .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

strs <- structure(list(strings = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", "P00492")), 
                  .Names = "strings", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

---

With regard to the extended example you added to your question: The reason you are getting that error is because you are trying to compare factor-variables with character-variables. See the difference in output between `sapply(strs,class)` and `sapply(lut,class)`:

```
> sapply(strs,class)
strings1 strings2 strings3 strings4 strings5 
"factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" 
> sapply(lut,class)
         V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

It is therefore necessary to convert the `factor`'s to `character`'s first and then do the comparison. The following code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(strs)[, lapply(.SD, as.character)
            ][, paste0('colids.',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), 
              by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

now gives the correct output:

```
   strings1 strings2 strings3 strings4 strings5         colids.1         colids.2         colids.3         colids.4         colids.5
1:   O75663   O95456   O95456   O95400   P00492       1, 3, 5, 7 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8       1, 3, 5, 7                 
2:   O95400   O75663   O95801   P00492   O95400       1, 3, 5, 7       1, 3, 5, 7             4, 8                        1, 3, 5, 7
3:   O95433   P00492   P00352   O95456   P00352       1, 3, 5, 7                              4, 8 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8             4, 8
4:   O95456   P00352   P00492   O95801   O75663 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8             4, 8                              4, 8       1, 3, 5, 7
5:   O95670   O95433   O75663            O95433 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8       1, 3, 5, 7       1, 3, 5, 7                        1, 3, 5, 7
6:   O95801            O95400            O95801             4, 8                        1, 3, 5, 7                              4, 8
7:                     O95670            O95670                                   2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8                  2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8
8:                                       O95456                                                                     2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8
```

---

*Used data extended example*:

```
strs <- structure(list(strings1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801"), class = "factor"), 
                       strings2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95433", "O95456", "P00352", "P00492"), class = "factor"), 
                       strings3 = structure(c(4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", "P00492"), class = "factor"), 
                       strings4 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O95400", "O95456", "O95801", "P00492"), class = "factor"), 
                       strings5 = structure(c(8L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", "P00492"), class = "factor")), 
                  .Names = c("strings1", "strings2", "strings3", "strings4", "strings5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

lut <- structure(list(V1 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", NA, NA), 
                      V2 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), 
                      V3 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
                      V4 = c("O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA), 
                      V5 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", NA, NA), 
                      V6 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), 
                      V7 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
                      V8 = c("O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA)), 
                 .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: one request, here that you make the columns [, c('colids1','colids2') if my data is huge then I cannot manually do that, would it be possible to have as many columns as my data with names like colids1 to ....

Comment: I have tried to use paste0 , but it did not get me any closer col <- colnames(strs)
df<- setDT(strs)[, paste0(c('c'), rep(col,each=1)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]

Comment: @nik Supposing all the columns are string-columns, you can use `setDT(strs)[, paste0('colids.',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]`. If you only want to do this for a specific set of columns, you can then specify them with `.SDcols` like this for example: `setDT(strs)[, paste0('colids.',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs), .SDcols = names(strs)[1:2]][]`

Comment: it gives me an error Error in lut == x : comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In is.data.frame(x) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="

Comment: @nik Did you you convert to a `data.table` with `setDT`? Did you also check the column classes?

Comment: @ Procrastinates Maximus the same error str(lut)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3805 obs. of  728 variables:  str(strs)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 58 obs. of  211 variables: and also df1<- setDT(lut)
df2 <- setDT(strs)

Comment: I tried to do it but it is huge and I cannot even copy and past it. Give me a minute, I am thinking to get a representative data so that you can work on it. Would you like I ask a question? so that you can also get the credit

Comment: I think I understood where the problem is. You assume that the length of all strs are the same, while in my real data it is not , they have different length !!!

Comment: Yes exactly this is the problem. I made an example data above in my question. Please have a look at it

Comment: @nik See the updated answer. As I said in a previous comment, the error occurs because of differences in column classes.

Comment: you are right, another problem happens. This calculate them but the problem is that it also find similar empty elements from strs to lut in my real data !!! it is making me crazy , do you have any idea why I am getting this ?

Comment: @nik I thing the problem should be solved if you replace the empty elements with `NA`-values.

Comment: @nik I've also added an answer to your follow upquestion which show how to tackle the class-differences the data.table-way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116586/discussion-between-procrastinatus-maximus-and-nik).