# manipulating two data frames based on string with different lengths

Tags: r

I have asked a question here [Finding the index based on two data frames of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211089/finding-the-index-based-on-two-data-frames-of-strings) and I got a perfect answer. 
Now I have been facing another problem which I could not solve it. if my second data is more than one column then I can solve it based on

```
setDT(strs)[, c('colids1','colids2') := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

This is ok as long as my second data (strs) has the same length in all columns
but if they vary (not in the same length) then this does not work and give me an error.

So let say my first data is

```
lut <- structure(list(V1 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", NA, NA), 
    V2 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), V3 = c("O75663", 
    "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), V4 = c("O95456", 
    "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA), V1 = c("O75663", "O95400", 
    "O95433", NA, NA), V2 = c("O95456", "O95670", NA, NA, NA), 
    V3 = c("O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670"), 
    V4 = c("O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", NA)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

and my second data is

```
strs <- structure(list(strings = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", 
"O95670", "O95801"), class = "factor"), strings2 = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95433", 
"O95456", "P00352", "P00492"), class = "factor"), strings3 = structure(c(4L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O75663", "O95400", 
"O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", "P00492"), class = "factor"), 
    strings4 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "O95400", "O95456", "O95801", "P00492"), class = "factor"), 
    strings5 = structure(c(8L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("O75663", 
    "O95400", "O95433", "O95456", "O95670", "O95801", "P00352", 
    "P00492"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("strings", "strings2", 
"strings3", "strings4", "strings5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

This is what I tried to do

```
df<- setDT(strs)[, paste0('colids_',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

it works if the length of strs is the same but it does not work when the length is varies as an example I gave here

Comment: The error was pretty clear. Try this `strs[c(1:3,5)] <- lapply(strs[c(1:3,5)], as.character)` and then run your `data.table` statement. Does the resultant `df` match your expectations?

Comment: @Sumedh thanks for your message, it does not solve the problem. I did do as you said and then I did df<- setDT(strs)[, paste0('colids_',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]   then same error I got .

Comment: @Sumedh I have been trying every single comment available in the web, but i don't know why it does not work!!!

Comment: My apologies, the first time I must have done something with the `strs` dataframe. Try `strs[,c(1:5)] <- lapply(strs[,c(1:5)], as.character)`, and then run your code. In short, convert all the variables in the `strs` dataset from `factor` to `character` class

Comment: Can you please try clearing the workspace and try? Its working fine for me now. I am using `data.table v1.9.6`

Comment: @nik You must do this strs[] <- lapply(strs, as.character)

Comment: @Sumedh thanks, the same error, but when I use strs[] <- lapply(strs, as.character) i get it run !! this is what i wanted

Comment: strange, it worked for me. Glad the other solution worked for you.

Comment: @Sumedh please post your answer so that I can at least like it and appreciate learning from you!

Comment: @Sumedh no need to assign it again with `<-`, see my answer a more data.table-way

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus, thanks! Still learning about `data.table`.

Comment: @nik, I really appreciate the gesture, but it really wasn't an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your factor variables in `strs` to character variables, can also easily be done with `data.table`. Supposing your `strs` dataset is already a `data.table`, you should do:

```
strs[, names(strs) := lapply(.SD, as.character)]
```

If `strs` is not already a data.table, you should use:

```
setDT(strs)[, names(strs) := lapply(.SD, as.character)]
```

After that you can perform the operation just like you wanted. Everything chained together, it looks like:

```
setDT(strs)[, lapply(.SD, as.character)
            ][, paste0('colids_',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), 
              by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable comment, I already like your answer, great !!! would it be possible to have a look at my real data? once you look I can remove them from the web. Thanks

Comment: great, thanks bro, I also accepted your answer since it is very informative and i learn from it a lot. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This I leant it from @scentoni ,*rapply* is a recursive version of *lapply* it converts all your vectors to character. the rapply mode called **how** , if it is set as replace **how = "replace"**, then each element of the list which is not itself a list and has a class included in classes is replaced by the result of applying function which is **as.character** here to the element.

```
strs <- rapply(strs, as.character, classes="factor", how="replace")
```

then perform

```
df<- setDT(strs)[, paste0('colids_',seq_along(strs)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(which(colSums(lut == x, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))), by = 1:nrow(strs)][]
```

Comment: this one also works!! can you please comment on the function ?